# add and remove classes with respective to activeIndex using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to move sections up and down on the wheel event by changing class on previous, inView and next sections. so every wheel event will change the activeIndex and hence classes to each sections. Also when the window is loaded the starting activeIndex = 0 so that it always starts from the top. i want to know is my approach correct? is it correct to add class to activeIndex and classes to sections before and after like:

```
Var previousSection = section[activeIndex - 1];
previousSection.classList.add("previous")
Var inViewSection = section[activeIndex];
inViewSection.classList.add("inView");
Var nextSection = section[activeIndex + 1];
nextSection.classList.add("next");
```

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style>
        home, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            user-select: none;
        }
            section {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                transition: 1s ease-out;
            }
                .first {background-color:black;}
                .second {background-color:red;}
                .third {background-color:blue;}
                .fourth {background-color:green;}
                .fifth {background-color:yellow;}
                .inView {top: 0;}
                .previous {top: -100vh;}
                .next {top: 100vh;}
    </style>
    <script>
        window.load = function() {
             var activeIndex = 0;
        }

        window.addEventListener("wheel", event => {
            const delta = Math.sign(event.deltaY);
            //console.info(delta);
            if (delta > 0) {
                nextSection();
            }
            else if (delta < 0) {
                previousSection();
            }
        });
            section: document.querySelectorAll(".section");
            activeIndex: 0;
        function nextService() {
            if (activeIndex = sections.length) return;
            let previousService = section[activeIndex - 1];
            previousService.classList.add("previous");
            let activeService = section[activeIndex];
            activeService.classList.add("inView");
            let nextService = section[activeIndex + 1];
            nextService.classList.add("next");
            activeIndex++;
            //update the above variables
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="first section"></section>
    <section class="second section"></section>
    <sectionc class="third section"></sectionc>
    <section class="fourth section"></section>
    <section class="fifth section"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you don't have an actual issue with your code I suggest that you create a post a [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to let people review your code and make suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Var` as capital letter. It must be `var` with lowercase.

Wrong

```js
Var previousSection = section[activeIndex - 1];
Var inViewSection = section[activeIndex];
Var nextSection = section[activeIndex + 1];
```

Correct

```js
var previousSection = section[activeIndex - 1];
var inViewSection = section[activeIndex];
var nextSection = section[activeIndex + 1];
```